# using jquery to create copies of elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to accomplish the follow copy elements from the one table to other when a user do a click in a button, the problem it's i don't know how copy an element modifying the id. I know that exit's a function called clone but i don't know if with this function if the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#yourelement').clone().attr('id','newID').appendTo('#newContainer');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that exit's a function called clone but i don't know if with
>   this function if the best way

That's the easiest way AFAIK.

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. When used in conjunction
>   with one of the insertion methods, **.clone() is a convenient way to
>   duplicate elements on a page**.

***Note*** that `clone` clones the element along with **data** as well as any associated **events**. If you need to remove a certain event from cloned element, you can use the `unbind` function.

Comment: `If you need to remove a certain event from cloned element, you can use the unbind function.`

or you could do `.clone(false)`